# Convert from tiff to other multipage format

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I am looking for a way to convert tif files into pdf or image format with multiple files using plsql. What I need to achieve is displaying converted pdf (or other format) with multiple pages from tif file and show it in browser.

What I did so far was to convert from tif to png but since png it's single file it's not what i'm looking for .

```
ordsys.ordimage.process(dest_loc, 'fileFormat=PNG');
ordsys.ordimage.getproperties(dest_loc, v_clob);
```

Chrome and Firefox doesn't support TIFF format anymore.

Or any other idea it's great. Thank you!

Comment: I'm a great fan of PL/SQL but this task doesn't seem like a natural fit for the language. Any reason why you must do this in database code?

Comment: Well my files are tiff files stored in bfile. I am getting them, convert into blob and display in Apex but Chrome and Firefox removed support for tiffs. I have no idea how to do this to be honest, i'm searching since yesterday with no luck. Can you suggest anything ? I was thinking about using java but never worked with "CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE" and still have to read more about this.

Comment: Oh, BLOBs. That makes sense. But still not sure

Comment: I think the java stored procedure is the way to go... I did something like that once, for rendering custom vector data into jpg image.